# Displaying a Dialog via IntentService?

Tags: android, service, dialog, android-alertdialog, intentservice

I have an IntentService where I am trying to display a Dialog with a message after some procedures have finished.

I can show a Toast by doing

```
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(ServiceName.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
```

but I want to display a Dialog instead, since it can display more text and looks cleaner for what I am trying to do. But when I try:

```
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(ServiceName.this)
                    .setTitle("Title")
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .create().show();
        }
    });
```

It throws an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with this activity.

I don't want to go fiddling around with my Manifest because that might affect everything else in the app, but is there any way around this? Can I somehow pass an AppCompatActivity into the IntentService? Can I somehow associate the IntentService with AppCompat? What are my options?

Edit: Trying to use the Dialog Activity approach:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ServiceName.this, ActivityWithDialogTheme.class);
intent.putExtra(ActivityWithDialogTheme.MESSAGE, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow pass an AppCompatActivity into the IntentService?

No.

> Can I somehow associate the IntentService with AppCompat?

No.

> What are my options?

Create a dialog-themed activity, and start that activity from your service.

Or, have the service post a message on an event bus saying that the procedures have finished. If you happen to have an activity in the foreground, it can pick up the event bus message and display the dialog. If you do not have an activity in the foreground, your service can find and and do something else (e.g., show a `Notification`), so as to not interrupt the user.

Comment: What do you mean by posting on the event bus? How do I get an Activity to pick it up? As for Notifications I'm not familiar but seems like a good thing to learn

Comment: @KaliMa: "What do you mean by posting on the event bus?" -- I mean using an event bus, [such as `LocalBroadcastManager`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager) or [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot3). "How do I get an Activity to pick it up?" -- that is part of using the event bus. The links earlier in this comment are to sample projects demonstrating the use of both of those buses, for a UI or a `Notification` to be the result of service work (in this case, triggered by `AlarmManager`).

Comment: Does this imply I am without options if I don't figure out how to use EventBus in this situation?

Comment: @KaliMa: As I wrote, you can create a dialog-themed activity, and start that activity from your service.

Comment: As in, an Activity that has no XML and just launches a Dialog from its on create method, launched via start activity with an intent?

Comment: @KaliMa: No, I mean an activity with a dialog theme. Since you are using `appcompat-v7`, that would be `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog`, `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`, etc.. Normal themes have the activity fill the screen. Dialog themes have the activity's window merely wrap its contents. Most of the system "dialogs" that you see are actually activities, using dialog themes. The approach that you propose could work, using `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`, but using a dialog theme is simpler.

Comment: But then do I have to define the layout, the message box, the buttons, the title etc myself with XML for that activity?

Comment: @KaliMa: Correct.

Comment: I'll probably try that route. Thanks!

Comment: I just got around to implementing this, is this an expected error? `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?` In the Manifest I gave the Activity the attribute `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog" `

Comment: if I add the flag it kind of works (the message appears but the underlying IntentService seems to "freeze")

Comment: @KaliMa: Sorry, but I do not know what "seems to freeze" means in this context.

Comment: My IntentService also communicates with another Activity (the one that called the IntentService) to display a ProgressDialog as its performing tasks. However if I display the Dialog activity, the ProgressDialog doesn't disappear like it normally does even though the broadcast signal is sent telling it to do so (I log the events to the console, e.g. "ProgressDialog dismissed").

Comment: @KaliMa: I am uncertain how you have implemented "communicates with another Activity" and why you did not just use that mechanism to display the dialog that you requested in this question. Services should not assume the existence of an activity, as the **point** behind a service is to be able to do work beyond the lifecycle of an individual activity or when you have no UI at all. Perhaps the right answer is to eliminate the service and the separate dialog, folding everything into this one activity.

Comment: @KaliMa: But, beyond that, if you show a new activity (themed like a dialog), it takes over the foreground from your other activity, which may interrupt your service's communications with that other activity.